# Maven The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly - even though it looks right

Tags: java, macos, maven

I cannot run Maven from terminal on MacOS because it says

> The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly, this
> environment variable is needed to run this program.

Every Google hit on the problem says not to have a space in your export command ... I only wish it were that simple ... here is some output

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_311.jdk/Contents/Home'
mvn -version

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

ls $JAVA_HOME

COPYRIGHT               THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt     jmc.txt                 man
LICENSE                 bin                             jre                     release
README.html             include                         legal                   src.zip
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt                      javafx-src.zip          lib

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version

java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)
michael on Mikes-MacBook-Pro (c for commands)

mvn

The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.

export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home'
echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home

export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_311.jdk/Contents/Home'
echo $JAVA_HOME

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_311.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I even moved my .bash_profile to another folder and started a new session. I also tried a brew uninstall then a brew install ... with no luck.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Inside the mvn command, which is a script, here is where it is apparently failing:

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ] ; then
  JAVACMD="`\\unset -f command; \\command -v java`"
else
  JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi

if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  echo "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly," >&2
  echo "this environment variable is needed to run this program." >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

I copied this line

JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"

and used it ... this was my results ... so no idea why it's failing inside the script - but my knowledge of bash script is very limited.

```
JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
$JAVACMD -version

java version "1.8.0_311"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_311-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.311-b11, mixed mode)
```

I even modified the script to this

```
echo $JAVACMD
if [ ! -x "$JAVACMD" ] ; then
  echo "The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly," >&2
  echo "this environment variable is needed to run this program." >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

And this is my output

```
mvn

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

Next, I took out the negative test in the if then statement so it would pass and now its saying this:

```
mvn

/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec/bin/mvn: line 194: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.8.5/libexec/bin/mvn: line 194: exec: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Im going to check folder permissions in that Library folder.

Comment: The mvn command is a shell script.  Look inside

Comment: @g00se - OK true, but there is no evidence like photo evidence ... and this is weird enough for a photo ☺

Comment: This question might be better suited for [su].

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - You're correct, it is a script ... but it is also a clean script having just done an uninstall, a fresh download then an install of maven. But I am looking through it to see if there is anything obvious

Comment: *JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home* looks wrong though I'm not a Mac user. What does `find /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk -name javac` give you?

Comment: @g00se - I updated the question with new info

Comment: @g00se thr output of the find command is this: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac. - and that is correct, Ive been working Java SDKs on Macs for years ...

Comment: OK. So it is 'right' probably ;) Weird thing is that on my Linux system Maven doesn't complain if no `$JAVA_HOME` is set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243117/discussion-between-g00se-and-michael-sims).

Comment: You may want to run the mvn shell script with additional flags so you can see what is going on.  `sh -xv somewhere/mvn`.   This should demonstrate what happens to trigger the message, and you can then compare it to what you should be expecting.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - I'm picking up this conversation in the chat that g00se linked us to but in case you don't make it over there ... look at my last update in my OP. It looks like maven has the path correct but it can't access any files in the path for some reason ... I'm investigating that now ... but if you hadn't told me that mvn was a script, I wouldn't have gotten this far ... I assumed it was a compiled program, so thank you for that.

Answer (score 4):

Ultimately, the problem was that the `mvn` command (which again is a script, not a compiled program) makes a call to `$HOME/.mavenrc` and inside of that file, was a different path assignment for `$JAVA_HOME` which was identical to my path, but instead of referencing jdk17.0.2, it was trying to reach jdk17.0.1 and I had uninstalled that jdk long enough prior to having this problem that I had forgotten I removed it.

Nonetheless, one expects a command that one executes to rely on live environment variables that are in place and not to refer to some other file that has a re-definition for an existing environment variable.

I blame Maven for not having their script first check the live environment for the paths it needs before deferring to one that was defined in the past.

Comment: THIS IS REALLY FRUSTRATING. Maven.. keep your act together. I spend around an hour to debug this issue!! Thanks Michael!